# Example of a submodule $N\subseteq M$ (over some commutative ring) such that the morphism $N\otimes M\to M\otimes M$ is not injective.

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

I would like to find an example of a submodule $N\subseteq M$ (over some commutative ring) such that the morphism $N\otimes M\to M\otimes M$ is not injective. Notice that the ambient module is the same as the one we're tensoring with (this is the point of the question).

Comment: Would you tell me why you gave this a -1? (One minute after it was posted).  Is this obvious in your opinion? If so, would you enlighten me?

Comment: Find any example in which you tensor with a module P, and then replace M and P by M\oplus P.

Comment: Just ignore the downvotes. They are mostly meaningless. If anyone had anything useful to tell you they would have written a comment.

Comment: This question only makes sense in the commutative case; otherwise there's no way to take the tensor product (since you'd be tensoring two left or two right modules).

Comment: Thanks, @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez! Apparently, it is almost obvious, I should have thought of that. As for the -1 vote, I don't care, but I was surprised to see it essentially immediately after I posted the question...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, thanks for the comment. I was interested in the question in the commutative case. However, I would think that if $M$ is a two-sided $R$-module and $N$ is a two-sided submodule of $M$, then it would make sense, no? Also, it would make sense as tensor over $\mathbb Z$. But, as I said already, I was interested in the commutative case anyway. Thank you.

Comment: If you take the tensor product over $\mathbb{Z}$ then there's no need to discuss a module structure at all. Yes, it would make sense for bimodules, but usually when people want to talk about bimodules they say "bimodules."

Comment: Dear @QiaochuYuan, Thank you for your comment! I bow before the altar of your mathematical superiority. I am also honored that you grace my humble post with your divine attention. It means a lot to me. However, let me recall that this was initiated by my innocent, parenthetical comment of preferring commutative rings. You felt compelled to point out that in the simplistic interpretation of my question it would not make sense otherwise. You were, of course, correct, but I tried to point out that a more careless reader might end up adding an answer that would perhaps satisfy the... (cont'd)

Comment: ...essence of the assumptions, but it could involve bimodules. In my carelessness I did not point out that I was not interested in bimodules, as you cleverly point out, if I did I would have said so, but, forgive me for this foolishness, I assumed that someone might read the question and think ``Uh, I know an example of this involving bimodules.'' Of course, that was silly, but with my limited intellect, I hadn't foreseen that that was nearly impossible...(cont'd)

Comment: Finally, I do want to thank you for making me realize why so many young people dislike mathoverflow (yes, I know, this isn't *even* mathoverflow!). It is, perhaps, because of arrogant people whose main motivation is not helping the person who asked a question, but to flaunt their mathematical prowess. Perhaps this is also something @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez would advise to ignore, so I will. :)

Comment: My apologies, that was not my intention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R=k[\![x,y]\!]$ with $\mathfrak{m}=(x,y)$. Take $M:=\mathfrak{m}$ and let $N:=\mathfrak{m}^2=(x^2,xy,y^2)$. Then $N \subseteq M$ and there is a short exact sequence
$$0 \to \mathfrak{m}^2 \to \mathfrak{m} \to \mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2 \to 0$$

The module on the right is isomorphic to $k^{\oplus 2}$. We note by dimension shifting that $\operatorname{Tor}^R_1(\mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{m}) \cong \operatorname{Tor}^R_3(k,k)$. Since $R$ has global dimension $2$ (or one can compute the minimal free resolution of $k$ and argue directly), we thus have $\operatorname{Tor}^R_1(\mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{m})=0$. Applying $-  \otimes_R \mathfrak{m}$ and considering the long exact sequence in $\operatorname{Tor}$, we get an exact sequence
$$0 \to \operatorname{Tor}^R_1(k^{\oplus 2},\mathfrak{m}) \to \mathfrak{m}^2 \otimes_R \mathfrak{m} \to \mathfrak{m} \otimes_R \mathfrak{m} \to k^{\oplus 2} \otimes_R \mathfrak{m}.$$ By dimension shifting, $\operatorname{Tor}^R_1(k^{\oplus 2},m) \cong \operatorname{Tor}^R_2(k,k)^{\oplus 2}$. But $R$ is a local ring of global dimension $2$, so $\operatorname{Tor}^R_2(k,k) \ne 0$. In fact, one can show directly by computing the minimal free resolution of $k$, that $\operatorname{Tor}^R_2(k,k) \cong k$. Thus the induced map $\mathfrak{m}^2 \otimes_R \mathfrak{m} \to \mathfrak{m} \otimes_R \mathfrak{m}$ is not injective.

Comment: Dear @metalspringpro, thank you for your answer. This looks great. Could you explain "dimension shifting"? Especially the first one. Thank you!

Comment: @Earl Dimension shifting is a term for results to the effect that if you have an exact sequence $0 \to \Omega M \to P \to M \to 0$ and $P$ is projective (or flat), then $\operatorname{Tor}^R_i(\Omega M,N) \cong \operatorname{Tor}^R_{i+1}(M,N)$ for any $i \ge 1$ and any $R$-module $N$. There are similar results for $\operatorname{Ext}$ (and both of these can be extended to even more generality if one desires) as well.

Comment: For the claim that $\operatorname{Tor}^R_1(\mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{m}) \cong \operatorname{Tor}^R_3(k,k)$, note that there is an exact sequence $0 \to \mathfrak{m} \to R \to k \to 0$. Applying dimension shifting twice reveals $\operatorname{Tor}^R_1(\mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{m}) \cong \operatorname{Tor}^R_2(k,\mathfrak{m}) \cong \operatorname{Tor}^R_3(k,k)$.

Comment: If you prefer, it can be seen more directly: the minimal free resolution of $\mathfrak{m}$ over $R$ is $0 \to R \xrightarrow{\begin{pmatrix} -y \\ x \end{pmatrix}} R^{\oplus 2} \to \mathfrak{m} \to 0$. Tensoring with $\mathfrak{m}$, it's not too hard to directly compute that $\operatorname{Tor}^1_R(\mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{m})=0$.

Comment: An advantage of the approach I originally used though, is that it can be used to construct larger families of examples. Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a local (Noetherian) ring and $M$ a finitely generated nonfree $R$-module. If $\operatorname{Tor}^R_1(M,M)=0$, then taking $N=\mathfrak{m}M$ we will always have that $N \otimes_R M \to M \otimes_R M$ not injective by a nearly identical argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very useful!